# Does Docker need to be installed ona Windows server that's hosting a GitLab CICD runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci, code-coverage, code-security

I'm using an on-premise hosted GitLab andt have a CI/CD pipeline which builds a .NET 6 application, executes unit tests and deploys the binaries to a ZIP file for later deployment.  I want to add code-coverage and code security scanning to the pipeline but to use those features provided in GitLab, it seems I need to use Docker?

So how does that work?

Does the code-coverage and security pipeline script exist in a Docker container that needs to be downloaded from GitLab and configured, or do I just need to install Docker on the Windows server and let GitLab do the rest?

I've read the docs provided by GitLab but I'm a bit confused about it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a GitLab runner configured with the docker [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) to take advantage of most of GitLab's builtin templates for things like security scanning. These jobs rely on docker images provided by GitLab.

In order to run a GitLab runner with the docker executor, you need Docker installed on the system.

This is noted in the documentation. For example, for [dependency scanning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/dependency_scanning/#enabling-the-analyzer), the documentation notes the following prerequisite:

> - On GitLab self-managed you need GitLab Runner with the docker or kubernetes executor. On GitLab.com this is enabled by default on the shared runners. The analyzer images provided are for the Linux/amd64 architecture.

But not *all* features require this. For example, code coverage reports only require that your CI job produce a coverage file in a supported format and the executor does not matter in this case.

```yaml
myjob:
  script:
    - make coverage  # produces the cobertura coverage file
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage.cobertura.xml
```

Comment: thanks @sytech, I am currently doing what you've described for code coverage, but I understand that GitLab provides much more in terms of code quality, dependency and security scanning, hence my question which you've answered :)